# is there possible to loop javascript function id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there possible to loop javascript function id? I have a form and the form is create using for loop; so I using this autosave javascript to save a draft; now the javascript only run the $("#remark1"). So I need to use for loop to loop the $("#remark1").

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            if (localStorage) {
                var content = localStorage.getItem("autoSave");
                if(content) {
                    $("#remark1").text(content);
                }
            }

            $("#remark1").autoSave(function() {
                var time = showTime();
                $("#msg").text("Draft Autosaved " + time).show();
            }, 2000);

            $("#refresh").click(function() {
                location.reload();
            });

            $("#clear").click(function() {
                localStorage.clear();
                location.reload();
            });

            function showTime() {
                var timeNow = new Date();
                var hours = timeNow.getHours();
                var minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
                var seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
                var timeString = "" + ((hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours);
                timeString += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
                timeString += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
                timeString += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
                return timeString;
            }
        });
```

I want to loop ("remark1"), any kind solution?

Comment: Loop the id to do what exactly?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Your question is still very unclear.  Are you saying that you have a `#remark2` and a `#remark3` that you would like to call `autoSave` on with the same arguments?

Comment: Your question is messy and confusing. It only saves `$('#remark1')` so you need to loop over `$('#remark1')` ?? It doesn't even compute. Please provide some markup and review your question. I cannot understand it in its current state.

Comment: @Frederik.L exactly yes. I am trying to loop over $('#remark1') something like $('#remark' + i) so will return remark1 and etc.

Comment: Why not use a class? `class="remark"`, and then `$(".remark").autoSave()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
function dynamicSave( id ) {
    $("#" + id).autoSave(function() {
        var time = showTime();
        $("#msg").text("Draft Autosaved " + time).show();
    }, 2000);
}

var ids = [ 'remark1', 'remark2' ];

ids.each(function(id) {
    dynamicSave( id );
});
```

Comment: You don't need the wrapping function in the call to `each`.  `ids.each(dynamicSave)` will suffice.

Comment: I'm aware of that but we don't know how or what he's going to be looping through and this will be a more familiar syntax - using shorthand like that with someone who's struggling with basic javascript just raises more questions than it answers.